# Matching two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, intersect

I have a two tables. TableA has two columns and TableB has one column.

### TableA

ID | TERM_A

### TableB

TERM_B

TERM_A and TERM_B column contain terms .
I want to take intersect terms from TERM_A column of TableA and TERM_B column of TableB with sql on Oracle 10.
My result table should be like that :

- ## Result_Table

  ID | INTERSECT_TERMS

How can I do that?

Comment: Hmmmm, it's a guess but you might be after the INTERSECT keyword: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The INTERSECT operator returns a resultset containing the matching values from the two queries.

```
select * from tableA
where term_a in 
    ( select term_a from tableA
      intersect
      select term_b from tableB )
;
```

Because you want to select additional columns from TABLEA you need to use the output of the intersection as a sub-query.